# Create a form submission redirect with terms and conditions using ONLY html?

Tags: html, forms, redirect, submit

I don't know if this is possible, but is there any way I can create a form that has a conditional submit button (with a "terms and conditions" checkbox) where the submit button redirects to another page upon completion, prevents access to the page if they haven't checking the "terms and conditions" box (as in, if they tried to merely type in the url of the destination page, they wouldn't be able to), AND do all this ONLY using html? I have very little knowledge of coding, but the other similar answers I have found on here either have elements of javascript/php/other non-html elements in the code (which doesn't work for my purposes) or they don't have all the elements (terms and conditions, submit button, redirect) that I need. How would I accomplish this task?

Comment: To prevent the user from typing in the destination URL without agreeing, the destination page would need to have some sort of validation code to verify the user has agreed to your terms. I can't think of a way, off the top of my head, to do this without using some type of code (server side or client).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Jquery Or Javascript,

**Jquery:**

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#submit-button" ).click(function( event ) {           
               var isChecked = $("#terms").is(":checked");

               if(!isChecked){    
                   alert("Select Terms!");         
                 return false;
               }
            });        
        });
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
 <form id="yourform" method="post" action="yourpage.php">
            <input id="terms" name="terms"  type="checkbox" value="yes"> Terms

             <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" name="submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is: NO.  You cannot accomplish what you want with HTML alone.

Answer to your second question: JavaScript can be used to require your HTML "Terms" checkbox to be CHECKED in order to submit your form (whose action could be the page you wish to "redirect" to). Krish's JS is fine for this example.

HOWEVER, the page the user is "redirected" to, can be accessed by visiting it directly. Preventing that is a whole different story.